# how to filter/search list items and markers

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

The objective is to filter the display of list elements and corresponding markers.I'm unable to understand what is wrong with the logic. The search input should filter and when you undo/cancel the search input then the list should reappear with the markers.

HTML:

```
enter <html>
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <title> Neighborhood Map</title>

 <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
 <script src="js/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
 <script src="js/knockout-3.4.0.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
 <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div id="sidebar" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-5 col-md-3">
      <h1 id="header">Chennai City Cultural Hubs</h1>

      <div class="search-box">
       <input class="text-search" type="text" placeholder="Enter here" data-
        bind="textInput: query">
      </div>
      <div class= "list-box">
       <div class="menu" data-bind="foreach: filteredItems">
       <a  class="menu-item"data-bind="text: title, click: $parent.setLoc" >
       </a>
       </div>
    </div>
  </div>

 <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-8">
    <div id="map"></div>
 </div>

 </div>
 <script src="js/app.js"></script>
 </body>
 </html>
```

JS:

```
function appViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    this.query = ko.observable('');
    var filter = self.query().toLowerCase();

    this.locationArray = ko.observableArray([]);
    locations.forEach(function (item) {
        self.locationArray().push(item);
    });

    self.setLoc = function (clickedLoc) {
        var clickedData = clickedLoc.marker;
        google.maps.event.trigger(clickedData, 'click')
    };

    this.filteredItems = ko.computed(function () {
        if (!this.filteredItems) {
            return self.locationArray();
        } else {
            return ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.locationArray(), function (item) {
                var result = (item.title.toLowerCase().indexOf(filter) > -1)
                item.marker.setVisible(result);
                return result;
            });
        }
    }, self);
};
ko.applyBindings(new appViewModel());
```

An explanation and solution would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Issues:

- Your `filter` variable is not observable, so it won't update after instantiation. It's always an empty string, since by the time you assign it, `query()` returns `""`.
- Checking for `!this.filteredItems` in the computed does not do anything, because it will never be false. (`filteredItems` is a `ko.computed` instance, which will evaluate to `true`)

### Solution

You can rewrite your `filteredItems` to:

```
this.filteredItems = ko.computed(function () {
  var q = this.query().toLowerCase();
  if (!q) {
    // TODO (?): reset all `setVisible` props.
    return this.locationArray();
  }

  return this.locationArray()
    .filter(function(item) {
      var passedFilter = item.title.toLowerCase().indexOf(q) > -1;
      item.marker.setVisible(passedFilter);
      return passedFilter;
    });
}, self);
```

By calling `query` you create a dependency to any changes in the search input. By calling `locationArray` you ensure updates when the data source changes. Note that you'll need to make sure your `setVisible` logic executes, even when you clear the query...

### Remarks & tips

- If you want, you can swap out `Array.prototype.filter` with `ko.utils.arrayFilter`, but the `.filter` method is widely supported by now.
- You can create more (pure) computeds to separate logic. (E.g.: `const lowerQuery = ko.pureComputed(() => this.query().toLowerCase())`)
- I wouldn't call `setVisible` in the filter since it's an unexpected side effect. Why not make it `computed` as well?

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. 
`self.mylocations().forEach(function(location){
  location.visible(true); });`
This won't word inside the conditional if. It would be great if you could help me understand where I'm going wrong and what I should do. 
Thank you very much

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. Inside which conditional `if`?

Comment: I'm unable to execute the setVisible logic everytime I cancel the query. 
`var q = this.query().toLowerCase();
  if (!q) {
    self.mylocations().forEach(function(location){ 
       location.visible(true);
     });
    return this.locationArray();
  }`
What should I do. 

I really appreciate your patience. Thank you very much.

Comment: `self.myLocations().forEach(item => item.marker.setVisible(true))` should work...

Comment: I tried replacing with the code you gave. It did not work. 
I'm truly thankful for you help.
`self.filteredItems = ko.computed(function(){
    var filter = self.query().toLowerCase();

    if(!filter){
      self.mylocations().forEach(function (location){
        location.marker.setVisible(true);
      });
      return self.locationArray();
    }

    return this.locationArray().filter(function (item){

      var passedFilter = item.title.toLowerCase().indexOf(filter) > -1;
      item.marker.setVisible(passedFilter);
      return passedFilter;
    });
  }, self);`

Comment: I don't see any errors in that code, so you'll have to try to reproduce the error in a stack snippet/fiddle for me to be of any more help.